# Multiply all pairs of rows in a Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have an MxN Numpy array. I'd like to take each row of the array and multiply it element-wise by each row of the array, resulting in an MxMxN numpy array of the products.

```
le_input = np.array([
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0]
])

le_expected_output = np.array([
    [
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]
    ],
    [
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0]
    ]
])
```

I can of course do this with a for loop, and I've tried that, but I'm assuming there's a way faster way to do this within Numpy. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @Divakar - I appreciate that this is a duplicate question, but I was unfamiliar with the "outer product" terminology, and as such wouldn't have been able to find the other question. I assume others may be in my position as well. How should such situations be handled? Should we update the original question to include other search terms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `np.einsum`:

```
np.einsum('ik,jk->ijk', le_input, le_input)
# array([[[0, 0, 1],
#         [0, 0, 0]],
#        [[0, 0, 0],
#         [0, 1, 0]]])
```

Or create a new axis and use array's broadcasting property to calculate the outer product on the first dimension:

```
le_input[:,None] * le_input
# array([[[0, 0, 1],
#         [0, 0, 0]],
#        [[0, 0, 0],
#         [0, 1, 0]]])
```